# Select all users I don't follow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

```
Users (id nvarchar(255), name)
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | A |

Followers (userId nvarchar(255), followId nvarchar(255), datetime)
| 1 | 2 | 6/11/2014 |
```

Let's say I am user 1 and I need to select all the users that have the name 'A' and I don't follow yet. For the above case the select should return:

```
| ID | Name |
| 4  |   A  |
| 5  |   A  |
```

How can I do this using an sql query?

I tried using the following query:

```
select u.id
from users u
left join followers f on u.id=f.userId
where f.id <> @userId
```

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Yes, I edited the question with an example which is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using a join.

```
SELECT U.ID, U.Name
FROM Users U
LEFT JOIN followers F
 on U U.ID = F.FollowID
WHERE
 u.Name = 'A'
 and U.ID <> 1
 AND F.FollowID is null
```

I'm told exist statements generally operate faster... so this may be better.

```
SELECT ID, Name 
FROM users U
WHERE NOT Exists 
 (SELECT 1 
  FROM followers F
  INNER JOIN Users U2
    ON F.User_ID = U2.ID
  WHERE U.ID = F.FollowID)
 and U.Name = 'A'
```

Comment: There is an extra parenthesis at the end. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Easy query, you can just use a NOT IN condition.

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 
Name = MyName AND ID NOT IN (SELECT followIdFROM Followers WHERE userId = MyId)
```

WHERE MyName is the user name, and MyId is the user ID, however you retrieve them

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work although i didn't tested

```
Select Id, Name from users Where Name =users.Name AND (Id not in (select followId from Followers where UserId = users.id) OR Id <> users.Id  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.id,u.name
from users u
left join followers f on u.id=f.userId
 and f.id <> @userId
where u.name='A'
```